# ZF2 - Validator chain not running on empty elements

Tags: validation, zend-framework2, xor

I have created a custom validator that requires 'house number' or 'flat number' to be filled out, but not both (XOR).

The validator works fine if both fields have been filled out (fail), or if one has been filled out (pass). But the validator does not run at all if both fields are empty.

Here is the input filter spec for both elements:

```
$input = new Input('flat_number');
$input->setRequired(true);
$input->setAllowEmpty(true);
$input->setValue($this->flatNumber);
$input->getValidatorChain()
        ->addValidator(new \Si\Validator\HouseFlatCheck('house_number'))
        ->addValidator(new \Zend\Validator\StringLength(array('max' => 30)));
$input->getFilterChain()->attach($this->defaultFilterChain);
$inputFilter->add($input);

$input = new Input('house_number');
$input->setRequired(true);
$input->setAllowEmpty(true);
$input->setValue($this->houseNumber);
$input->getValidatorChain()
        ->addValidator(new \Si\Validator\HouseFlatCheck('flat_number'))
        ->addValidator(new \Zend\Validator\StringLength(array('max' => 30)));
$input->getFilterChain()->attach($this->defaultFilterChain);
$inputFilter->add($input);
```

By the looks of things, validators do not run if the field is empty and passes the 'required' and 'allowEmpty' requirements.

Is there any way I can get the 'HouseFlatCheck' validator to run against my two elements despite both fields being empty?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a whole day of looking into this, I've found a route around the problem.

First off, the Zend\InputFilter\BaseInputFilter class contains the following for isValid():

```
public function isValid()
{
    if (null === $this->data) {
        throw new Exception\RuntimeException(sprintf(
            '%s: no data present to validate!',
            __METHOD__
        ));
    }

    $this->validInputs   = array();
    $this->invalidInputs = array();
    $valid               = true;

    $inputs = $this->validationGroup ?: array_keys($this->inputs);
    foreach ($inputs as $name) {
        $input = $this->inputs[$name];
        if (!array_key_exists($name, $this->data)
            || (null === $this->data[$name])
            || (is_string($this->data[$name]) && strlen($this->data[$name]) === 0)
        ) {
            if ($input instanceof InputInterface) {
                // - test if input is required
                if (!$input->isRequired()) {
                    $this->validInputs[$name] = $input;
                    continue;
                }
                // - test if input allows empty
                if ($input->allowEmpty()) {
                    $this->validInputs[$name] = $input;
                    continue;
                }
            }
            // make sure we have a value (empty) for validation
            $this->data[$name] = '';
        }

        if ($input instanceof InputFilterInterface) {
            if (!$input->isValid()) {
                $this->invalidInputs[$name] = $input;
                $valid = false;
                continue;
            }
            $this->validInputs[$name] = $input;
            continue;
        }
        if ($input instanceof InputInterface) {
            if (!$input->isValid($this->data)) {
                // Validation failure
                $this->invalidInputs[$name] = $input;
                $valid = false;

                if ($input->breakOnFailure()) {
                    return false;
                }
                continue;
            }
            $this->validInputs[$name] = $input;
            continue;
        }
    }

    return $valid;
}
```

As allowEmpty was true for my Input, the validation for that Input stops and moves on to the next Input element in the array. Changing allowEmpty to false on my Input solves that issue, but creates another, as the 'Zend\InputFilter\Input' class calls the following function during it's isValid() function:

```
protected function injectNotEmptyValidator()
{
    if ((!$this->isRequired() && $this->allowEmpty()) || $this->notEmptyValidator) {
        return;
    }
    $chain = $this->getValidatorChain();

    // Check if NotEmpty validator is already first in chain
    $validators = $chain->getValidators();
    if (isset($validators[0]['instance'])
        && $validators[0]['instance'] instanceof NotEmpty
    ) {
        $this->notEmptyValidator = true;
        return;
    }

    $chain->prependByName('NotEmpty', array(), true);
    $this->notEmptyValidator = true;
}
```

Because my field is required and allowEmpty is now false, a 'NotEmpty' validator is added to my chain automatically. Once that was discovered, the solution was simple. I created an 'Input' class in my custom library, which overrides the injectNotEmptyValidator function, forcing it to do nothing:

```
namespace Si\InputFilter;

class Input extends \Zend\InputFilter\Input {
    protected function injectNotEmptyValidator() {
        return;
    }
}
```

Doing the above menas that 'NotEmpty' is NOT added to my validator chain, so my XOR validator can run correctly. All I have to do now is use my corrected Si\InputFilter\Input class to populate InputFilter for those two elements.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

I'd do this differently: I'd create a custom input that accepts an array of values, representing both house number and flat number. The input would then contain a custom validator that does the XOR logic, and which would select the appropriate validation chain based on which was present. (Similarly, on the form side, I'd represent this as a composite element.)

Comment: I think in terms of re-use, the override solution works better for me. I will need to run custom validators that are triggered on fields (empty or not) later in my application. Thank you very much for the contribution though! Makes perfect sense!

Answer (score 1):

This appears to have been fixed recently as of 2.2.0: https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/pull/4165